# Why do flash players consume up to 20 times more CPU than VLC player to view exactly the same video file?

Tags: video, intel-graphics, flash, vlc

When I play a video (H264 MPEG4 AVC 320x180) online (in Firefox or Chrome) it uses to consume up to 100% CPU, but if I download it (exactly the file played) and use VLC - it takes just 5% (6% at maximum). Why does this happen and what can I do to make on-line players more efficient?

PS: The video card is Intel GMA X4500HD.

Comment: Is the file in the browser being played using Flash or using HTML5? What are the figures for playing in Totem (using GStreamer)?

Comment: I've already said that's Flash. I have no Totem to try, but I believe it wont be much worse than VLC.

Comment: I assume Flash-plugin + Browser (Firefox, Chrome,..) is a much more complex system than a movie player as VLC. I don't mean that movie players are simple, but I would guess there are less components interacting than within a browser.

Comment: Heavy CPU usage is not restricted to VIDEO but also applies to STREAMING AUDIO (e.g. RADIO stations) in Firefox or Chromium; streaming in VLC is sooo much more lightweight in comparison!

Answer (score 6):

The probable reason is that the Flash plugin cannot take advantage of any kind of hardware acceleration supported by your graphics card driver. Everything is then decoded using the CPU.

The Intel drivers present in your system allow VLC to use your GPU instead of your CPU to render the movie with video acceleration which is much better for obvious reasons.

Also, Flash hardware acceleration API (Stage Video) requires developers to actually add support for it into their video player SWFs.

If the video player does not have built in support for it even if the version of Flash you have does have VA enabled and your drivers support it (seems they do since VLC is apparently using it) your video will be decoded via the CPU.

Comment: But shouldn't Flash on Linux be able to make use of the graphics hardware acceleration since 10.2 beta? See http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=adobe_linux_vdpau&num=1

Comment: @nem75 not if the video player you are using was compiled without support or if the Flash plugin fails to use your video card acceleration features, remember we are talking here about an Intel, not a Nvidia or ATI.